# Room DB throwing SQLiteDatabaseCorruptException

Tags: android, android-room

In our application, we are using Room DB to store data locally.

In some of the devices of the users we are noticing that DB is throwing `SQLiteDatabaseCorruptException`

When we try to put a try/catch block on the DB operations with SQLException the Android studio is throwing error.

Is there any better way to handle this error apart from catching the exception?

Any pointers to this would be really appreciated..

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: This exception seems to point to deeper issues than can be solved by a try/catch block. You need to determine why the database is becoming corrupted.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice, any tips for identifying what exactly can cause the DB to be corrupted?

Answer (score 2):

The website [How To Corrupt An SQLite Database File](https://www.sqlite.org/howtocorrupt.html) enumerates some reason why db corrupts, maybe you can find some unreasonable usages and regulate it.
If `SQLiteDatabaseCorruptException` is still throws, there are some things we can do:

- backup db file and restore it when corruption happens
- repair db file

[wcdb](https://github.com/Tencent/wcdb) providers repairKit and we can use it easily.

Answer (score 1):

what are you storing? and how are you storing it? is the database becoming corrupt on a read or write?

here is what i have set up and have never had a database corruption

typical update

```
@Update
void updateCard(Card card);
```

updated from a repository

```
public void updateCard(Card card){
    new updateCard(cardDao, card).execute();
}


 private static class updateCard extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    private CardDao mDao;
    private Card card;

    updateCard(CardDao dao, Card card) {
        this.mDao = dao;
        this.card = card;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        mDao.updateCard(card);
        return null;
    }
}
```

but this is more likely to be a data issue than say a broken transaction

Comment: Data contains both Text & Numbers. It throwing error in both the cases some times on Read & sometimes on Write..

Comment: are you updating the database using room queries, nothing funny like raw queries and are you updating it in threads async task etc

Comment: All DB operations are using singleton object, hence it will not be possible for me to operate simultaneously from different locations. I am using the DAO to update the DB. Hope this answers your question.

Comment: maybe its something to do with how your validating the data before you insert it like someone trying to insert an infitely big string perhaps